# Regex regular expression coordinates

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-2-validation

trying to sort out a regular expression for the following string:

```
51.4920302, -0.0850667
```

So far I have:`@"^[0-9]*,{-}[0-9]*$"` but it doesn't seem to be working.

Any thought, greatly received.

The whole snippet is:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]*,{-}[0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "Must enter a valid coordinate")]
    public string FaveRunLatLng2 { get; set; }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You're not allowing for the decimal point.  You're also basically requiring the second part of the coordinates to be negative and not allowing the first.  Try

```
@"^-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+, -?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\b-?\d+\.\d+, -?\d+\.\d+\b
```

If you want the space to be optional, you can add \s?, like this:

```
\b-?\d+\.\d+,\s?-?\d+\.\d+\b
```

As long as you know your input is going to have a comma and space. If it is entered by a user, you may need to sanitize it first.

Here is a tester online you can use:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html